# How to allowed null Auto_Increment primary key in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, primary-key

[image]

`midx` column is the primary key that using auto increment (`identity 1,1`).

When I try to insert data using this query, that is a problem:

```
Insert into coordinfo(mdate, X, Y, lat, lon) 
values (GETDATE(), 12344, 334, 34.775, 123.554);
```

I want to increase the `midx` by automatically without entering the primary key.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you saying you want the `midx` column to be set to auto increment?

Comment: you mean an identity column? `IDENTITY(1,1)`

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen yes midx is primary key and using auto increment. i want to insert without entering midx

Comment: @mrtig yes!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: There is no such thing as a `primary key` that allows `null` values.  Not in SQL Server.  Not in any database.  The definition of "primary key" is that the value is not `NULL`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff when i use mysql it'is possible.. but mssql is not work..

Comment: What is the purpose of having a primary key if it can be `NULL`?  Think about it, you are saying you want a key with which it is impossible to know which lock to open.  This doesn't make much sense.

Comment: @HighEndGuy . . . By definition, `primary key` is not `null`, even in MySQL.  Here is one reference:  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/optimizing-primary-keys.html.

Comment: @GordonLinoff mysql ddl : CREATE TABLE `te` (
 `t1` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `t2` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 PRIMARY KEY (`t1`)
)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT=3                                                                                query : insert into te(t2) values(123) it'is possible without entering primary key

Answer (score 1):

Normally a primary key column cannot be null, since it has to be a clustered index on the table.

In order to get the effect you want, you should create a `keys` table with a non-null identity column.

If your table is defined as follows, with an insert trigger, your insert DML will yield an auto-generated value for `midx`:

```
CREATE TABLE keyTable 
(
    [key] int identity(1,1) primary key not null,
    date datetime
)

CREATE TRIGGER myTable_increment_midx ON myTable 
after INSERT 
AS 
BEGIN
    DECLARE @key int 
    INSERT INTO keyTable (date) values (getdate())
    SET @key = @@IDENTITY

    UPDATE t 
    set t.midx = @key
    FROM mytable t join INSERTED i on i.mdate = t.mdate and ...
END

CREATE TABLE myTable
(
     mdate DATETIME,
     udate DATETIME,
     midx  INT PRIMARY KEY NULL,  --again, you shouldn't be allowed to do this
     X     INT,
     Y     INT, 
     lat   DECIMAL(9, 6),
     lon   DECIMAL(9, 6) 
)
```

Comment: you don't understand that i already define idx auto increment. i want to insert query without entering primary key!

Answer (score 0):

you can use compete column:

```
ALTER TABLE coordinfo ADD midx AS idx*100
```